# On 7th day of Sukkos, were the willow branches placed round the altar only on the western and northern sides?

Tags: hoshana-rabbah, mizbeach-altar, arava

[The mishna in Sukkah 45a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.45a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states that

> “How is the mitzva of the willow branch fulfilled? There was a place
> below Jerusalem, and it was called Motza. They would descend there and
> gather willow branches [murbiyyot] from there. And they would then
> come and stand them upright at the sides of the altar, and the tops of
> the branches would be inclined over the top of the altar.”

The mishna continues:

> And after gathering the willow branches, they would then come and
> stand them upright at the sides of the altar. It was taught: The
> willow branches were numerous and long, and eleven cubits high, so
> that they would lean over the altar one cubit.

The Gemoro concludes from the statement that

> “The willow branches were numerous and long, and eleven cubits high,
> so that they would lean over the altar one cubit”

that the branches had to be placed on the base (עַל הַיְּסוֹד) otherwise they would not be long enough to  lean over the altar one cubit.

Now the base “surrounded the mizbeach only on the western and northern sides” (see e.g.[here](https://templeinstitute.org/illustrated-tour-the-mizbeach/)).

So it seems that the willow branches were only on the western and northern sides of the altar.

My question is whether this conclusion is correct or whether there were also willow branches on the eastern side and they had to be longer.